# AngularJS+OnsenUIで動的に多階層リストを生成したい

Tags: javascript, onsen-ui, angularjs

お世話になります。

[Accordion list with OnsenUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25037489/accordion-list-with-onsenui) を参考に、静的な多階層リストの生成はできました。
今回、動的な多階層リストの生成をしたく、質問させていただきます。

生成したいリストとして以下の機能を持たせたいです。

1. Ajaxを使用して取得したリストを表示

> A1
>   B1
>   C1
>   D1

2. リストのうち1つをタップするとAjaxを使用し、タップされたリストに関連するリストと「子リストを持つ」について true または false のどちらかを取得し、取得したリストの表示

> A1
>   B1
>   -- B1-1
>   -- B1-2
>   C1
>   D1

3. true の場合、2の繰り返し

> A1
>   B1
>   -- B1-1
>   -- B1-2
>   -- -- B1-2-1
>   -- -- B1-2-2
>   -- -- B1-2-3
>   C1
>   D1

4. false の場合、タップするとAjaxを使用し、タップされたリストに関連するリストだけ取得し、取得したリストの表示

以上

どこまで子リストを持つのかは固定しません。

[Accordion list with OnsenUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25037489/accordion-list-with-onsenui) に沿ってやろうとすると、ng-repeatの扱い方がわからず上手くいきません。どのようにすればよろしいのでしょうか。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 「angularjs 再帰ツリー」あたりでググると何通りかやり方が出てきますので参考にしてみてください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。参考にしてみます。